# SQL Server - How to add a column of percentile values of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I'd like to have a calculated field that gives me the percentile of a column's value in a table. What is the best way to do so?

I have a table with only one column containing values ranging from 0 to 10000, randomly distributed. I want to add another column to tell me what the percentile of the value on the same row is with respect to all the other values in the original column.

There are 2 definitions of percentile as explained here: http://onlinestatbook.com/chapter1/percentiles.html .

I am using the definition that I knew. Example: a value is at 25th percentile means 25% of the population is AT or below the value.

The algorithm I am thinking of is below, I hope someone can translate it to SQL for me because I am an SQL beginner:

For all the rows in my table, if the value is less than or equal to value in current row then count++. At the end of table, I do the division: count / number of rows to have my percentile. That's accurate enough for me because there are lots of rows.

Comment: Can we know for sure whether or not there are duplicates in the column? Also there seems to be some confusion as to what you mean by "percentile," so I really recommend adding some sample input and output to clear it up.

Comment: @Chris Cunningham: Here's what I mean by percentile: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile . Yes there can be duplicates, just like there are duplicates in SAT scores for example.

Comment: Give us example input and output. If the numbers are 1, 2, 3, and 4, do you think that 1's "percentile" is 10, or 0?

Comment: Chris, For 1, its percentile is 25 because 25% of the 'population' is at or below 1. For 2, the percentile is 50th...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edited to match comments in question]:

```
SELECT Number, 100 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number))/Count(*) AS Percentile
FROM MyTable
```

Then if your `Number`s are 2, 5, 10, and 14, you should get:

```
Number   Percentile
2        25
5        50
10       75
14       100
```

Here's the problem: if there are duplicates, then ROW_NUMBER will screw you up. If your `Number`s are 2, 5, 5, and 14, the code above will give you:

```
Number   Percentile
2        25
5        50
5        75
14       100
```

So... do this instead.

```
SELECT Number, MAX(100 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number))/Count(*)) AS Percentile
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Number
```

If your numbers are 2, 5, 5, 14, it should return

```
Number   Percentile
2        25
5        75
14       100
```

Comment: @Alex Aza: then the percentile would be the same as it is above.

Comment: @Chris Cunningham: Your example doesn't reflect the meaning of percentile as I understand it. Please refer to this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile

Comment: From your link: "a percentile (or centile) is the value of a variable below which a certain percent of observations fall. For example, the 20th percentile is the value (or score) below which 20 percent of the observations may be found." My number 5 is at the 25th percentile, below which 25 percent of the observations may be found.

Comment: Chris, In your example, 5 is 50th percentile because 50% of the values are at or below 5.

Comment: If you want to use "at or below" instead of below, then my newly-edited answer should work for you now, but that's not what Percentile means according to the page you linked me to -- and it's not how the College Board does it either. If you get an 800 on the Math SAT, your percentile will be 93%, because 93% of people are **below** you. You are demanding that we return 100% instead, since 100% of people are **at or below** you. Which is also fine, if that's what you mean by percentile.

Comment: There are 2 definitions of percentiles: "There is no universally accepted definition of a percentile. Using the 65th percentile as an example, the 65th percentile can be defined as the lowest score that is greater than 65% of the scores. This is the way we defined it above and we will call this "Definition 1." The 65th percentile can also be defined as the smallest score that is greater than or equal to 65% of the scores. This we will call "Definition 2." Unfortunately, these two definitions can lead to dramatically different results, especially when there is relatively little data."

Comment: Works for me -- sorry for the confusion. Did you try what I wrote to see if it gives you what you want? It looks like you went back and changed your question to ask for an implementation of a specific algorithm. :/

Comment: The last query doesn't appear to work. I got "Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."

Comment: That `COUNT(*)` aggregate function should be replaced by a `COUNT(*) OVER()` window function

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a computed column that would depend on other rows/tables.

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx):

> The expression can be a noncomputed
>   column name, constant, function, and
>   any combination of these connected by
>   one or more operators. The expression
>   cannot be a subquery.

However you can make a query:

Setup:

```
declare @Test table (Value int)

insert @Test
values
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (7),
    (10)
```

Query:

```
select *, (select sum(Value) from @Test t2 where t2.Value <= t1.Value) * 100.0 / sum(Value) over()
from @Test t1
```

Result:

```
Value       Percentile
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           3.125000000000
2           9.375000000000
3           18.750000000000
4           31.250000000000
5           46.875000000000
7           68.750000000000
10          100.000000000000
```

Comment: I've added some more info. How do the College Board people calculate percentile, I wonder? I want to be able to do the same in my table.

Comment: @@user776676 - let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Number <= 20 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float)/COUNT(*) as PercentileFor20
from Numbers;
```